# Error happens during Ionic project creation

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile-application

Error:

> Unable to get local issuer certificate
> at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1550:34)
> at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:514:28)
> at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:967:8)
> at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:743:12) {
> code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY',
> response: undefined
> }

I am using ng version

```
Angular CLI: 16.2.11
Node: 18.17.0
Package Manager: npm 9.6.7
OS: win32 x64
```

and ionic version 7.1.6

I am trying to off my firewall and proxy settings but it not working it showing the same error.